# Fetch APIs with Django RF, Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

I am working on an application to fetch multiple Rest api's, and in turn, expose the data from those fetches, in a Rest api.

The Api's I need to fetch are slow, and do not have the same structure. All fetches need to be recurrent, daily.

I am thinking of using :

-Django Rest Framework to expose the api, use the parsers and serializers to treat the data received, and store the aggregated data to be exposed, in a Postgresql.

-Celery to launch workers and/or child processes in parallel

-Celery beat to fetch regularly, and keep data up to date.

-RabbiMq as a message broker to Celery.

Can I use celery to make the fetch calls to the api's or do I need to write a special fetch script?

And how do I get the result back from Celery to Django RF to store it? Do I need to use another queue and celery worker for the response ?

Is it better to have 1 worker with multiple child processes, or multiple workers with 1 child process each ?

Comment: `And how do I get the result back from Celery to Django RF to store it? Do I need to use another queue and celery worker for the response ?` Have you tried using the result object returned by apply_async() and calling result.get()? More details here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html

Comment: I just checked it out, thank you @nick-odell , seems promising